# Cloudflare instead of nodebalancer in linode kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cloudflare, linode

there is a similar question regarding [cloudflare as a load balancer for the VPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/609812/using-cloudflare-as-the-only-load-balancer).
But in my case I'm looking for using cloudflare as a nodebalancer replacement for the linode kubernetes cluster.

Is there any chance I can make it work? Also, if there is a way to configure it to automatically detect a new nodes and remove the "dead" ones?